# How to run more than one css transition with a click on a button?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I am building an animated hamburger menu with html css js. I now know how to start a css transition with javascript. See https://jsfiddle.net/ralphsmit/byaLfox5/. My problem now is that I need to run more than one transition with a click on my button. I've put my code here https://jsfiddle.net/ralphsmit/v980ouwj/16/.

A short explanation of my code. I have made a button (for the sake of clarity I made it green with a low opacity) and when that button is clicked, the background .dsgn-header-background will appear. Now I also want the two rectangle for the menu to animate into a cross and that the the .dsgn-header-menu-opened-menuitems also fade in.

My question is, how do I modify this js code, so that more than one transition will be started? So all transitions are a different element. You'll find the full code in the JS fiddle above (feel free to edit this).

Javascript:

```
const background = document.querySelector('.dsgn-header-background');
const button = document.querySelector('.dsgn-header-button');

let open = false;

button.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);

function onClickPlay(){
  if(background.classList.contains('on')){
    background.classList.remove('on');
  }else{
    background.classList.add('on');
  }
}
```

Comment: what class you want to add for cross in menu

Comment: .dsgn-header-rectangle-down should become .dsgn-header-rectangle-down.on and .dsgn-header-rectangle-up should become .dsgn-header-rectangle-down.on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out.

```
function onClickPlay(){
  if(background.classList.contains('on')){
      background.classList.remove('on');
      element.classList.remove('anotherClassWithDifferentTransitions');
  }else{
      background.classList.add('on');
      element.classList.add('anotherClassWithDifferentTransitions');
  }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply! I mean in fact starting transitions with different element. So I don't mean transitioning two properties from the same element, but transitioning four, five or six elements, all with their own transition. Sorry if that wasn't clear!

Comment: Hey checkout my edited solution. Does that make any sense?

Comment: If I want to add another few elements, just add       element.classList.remove('anotherClassWithDifferentTransitions'); under the if and else?

Comment: Like this: function onClickPlay(){
  if(background.classList.contains('on')){
      background.classList.remove('on');
      element.classList.remove('anotherClassWithDifferentTransitions');
      elementtwo.classList.remove('anotherClassWithDifferentTransitions');

  }else{
      background.classList.add('on');
      element.classList.add('anotherClassWithDifferentTransitions');
      elementtwo.classList.remove('anotherClassWithDifferentTransitions');

  }
}

Comment: yes ralph that's it! Only if you want the transition on those elements to trigger at the same time yes you're right!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this , The changes is i have added 2 more constant variable which adding on class when menu open and remove on class when menu closes.

```
  const background = document.querySelector('.dsgn-header-background');
 const button = document.querySelector('.dsgn-header-button');
const menu_up = document.querySelector('.dsgn-header-rectangle-up');
const menu_down = document.querySelector('.dsgn-header-rectangle-down');

let open = false;

button.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);

function onClickPlay(){
  if(background.classList.contains('on')){
     background.classList.remove('on');
     menu_up.classList.remove('on');
     menu_down.classList.remove('on');
  }else{
    background.classList.add('on');
    menu_up.classList.add('on');
    menu_down.classList.add('on');

  }
}
```

hope this will help you .

Comment: Thanks for your help! That was also the suggestion of the others! I now use this code indeed. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 2):

```
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
const button = document.querySelector('.dsgn-header-button');

function onClickPlay() {content.classList.toggle('on');}

button.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s24mbakf/

Answer (score 1):

Add the other elements to your `onClickPlay` function as you did with demo.

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
const demo2 = document.querySelector('.demo2');
const buttondemo = document.querySelector('.buttondemo');

let open = false;

buttondemo.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);

function onClickPlay(){
 if(demo.classList.contains('on')){
            demo.classList.remove('on');
            demo2.classList.remove('on');
 } else {
            demo.classList.add('on');
            demo2.classList.add('on');
 }
}
```

```css
.demo {
  width: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transition: width 4s;
}

.demo.on {
  width: 100vw;
}

.demo2 {
  width: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transition: width 8s;
}

.demo2.on {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.buttondemo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"><div>
<div class="demo2"><div>
<div class="buttondemo"><div>
```